# Mysql delete statement with joins

Tags: mysql

I am trying to DELETE the first row in the students Table which joins the student class by by using the students first, middle and last name with the date of birth in the students table which references the CLASS in the Student_Class table. I having tried using the following statements but seems not to work.

```
delete from student where student.stu_id = (select student_class.stu_id from 
student_class left outer join student on student.stu_id = 
student_class.stu_id where student.first_name = 'Junior' AND 
student.middle_name = 'Mills' AND student.last_name = 'Prince' AND 
student.dob = '2015-10-02' AND student.sch_id = '2' AND student_class.class 
= 'J.H.S. 1');
```

And also :

```
delete student.* from student inner join student_class on 
student_class.stu_id  = student.stu_id where student.stu_id = (select 
student_class.stu_id from student_class left outer join student on 
student.stu_id = student_class.stu_id where student.first_name = 'Junior' 
AND student.middle_name = 'Mills' AND student.last_name = 'Prince' AND 
student.dob = '2015-10-02' AND student.sch_id = '2' AND student_class.class 
= 'J.H.S. 1');
```

[TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhLCq.jpg)

Comment: As an aside 'LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x' is the same as `INNER JOIN x...'

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you haven't just done a simple join for the delete:-

```
DELETE a
FROM student a
INNER JOIN student_class b
ON a.stu_id = b.stu_id 
WHERE a.first_name = 'Junior' 
AND a.middle_name = 'Mills' 
AND a.last_name = 'Prince' 
AND a.dob = '2015-10-02' 
AND a.sch_id = '2' 
AND b.class = 'J.H.S. 1'
```

but you appear to be wanting to delete a record from the *student* table (not the *student_class* table) and are specifying pretty much all the identifying fields from the *student* table anyway.